# sort a array according to another array, swift

Tags: arrays, swift, function, sorting

I am wondering is there any build-in function I can sort a array according to another array. For example: sort testStringArray according to testIntArray

`var testStringArray = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
 var testIntArray = [21, 3, 43, 5, 1]`

After the function, testStringArray will be

```
testIntArray.sort // [1, 3, 5, 21, 43]
testStringArray // ["e", "b", "d", "a", "c"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var array1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
var array2 = [21, 3, 43, 5, 1]

let sorted = zip(array1, array2).sort { $0.1 < $1.1 }

array1 = sorted.map { $0.0 }
array2 = sorted.map { $0.1 }

print(array1) // ["e", "b", "d", "a", "c"]
print(array2) // [1, 3, 5, 21, 43]
```

Something like this? I feel like it can be done better...

EDIT:

This doesn't feel like it's much better...

```
zip(array1, array2).sort { $0.1 < $1.1 }.forEach {
    array1.removeAtIndex(array1.indexOf($0.0)!)
    array1.insert($0.0, atIndex: array1.count)

    array2.removeAtIndex(array2.indexOf($0.1)!)
    array2.insert($0.1, atIndex: array2.count)
}

print(array1) // ["e", "b", "d", "a", "c"]
print(array2) // [1, 3, 5, 21, 43]
```

Comment: Yup. I am trying to find the simplest way to sort it because my way to do that is to define a new function to sort the second array according to the first array.

Comment: Well, my answer is pretty simple. It's just I feel like I can cut one more step :)

Comment: Ya. Yours is much simpler than mine. Thank you for your help

Comment: I think the first way you make is better because I don't want to modify the arrays.