# Swift - Sort a subset of an array

Tags: arrays, swift

I currently have a tableview with a lot of users, but I would like to sort the users in a specific order, not just ascending or descending. Let's say I have an array with the following users.

```
"User1", "1st grade"
"User2", "1st grade"
"User3", "kids"
"User4", "6th grade"
"User5", "5th grade"
"User6", "2nd grade"
"User7", "kids"
"User8", "juniors"
```

How can I order my array so that all the students who are in kids class are the first to be displayed, followed by all the classes with numbers (in order) and then all the Juniors.

**I want an array that can display this**

```
"User3", "kids"
"User7", "kids"
"User1", "1st grade"
"User2", "1st grade"
"User6", "2nd grade"
"User5", "5th grade"
"User4", "6th grade"
"User8", "juniors"
```

**Edit:**
Updated the text to make clear that the array has two columns, not just one string.

Was able to achieve it by using the line below

```
let sortedArray = 
self.userArray.sorted(by: { $0.SchoolGrade!.gradeLongName().contains("Kids") || 
$1.SchoolGrade!.gradeLongName().contains("Juniors") })
```

Comment: What's the structure of your object? If it's `[[String]]` you may want to change your data model. Else https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34957771/sort-a-array-according-to-another-array-swift ? and define the "age/class" logic because with just strings, it isn't.

Comment: I fixed it using the answer below. My structure contains the same stuff a database would have: mostly ints, including an int for the second column (grade). I  could indeed sort the array by using the int of the grade instead of the grade text itself, so I will look into it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swift has a sort algorithm that lets you sort using a closure. The closure should return true if the first arguement comes before the second argument.

```
let sortedArray = user.sorted(by: {

    ($0.gradeLongName().contains("kids") 
     || $1.gradeLongName()contains("juniors")  
     || $0.gradeLongName() < $1.gradeLongName())
    && !($0.gradeLongName().contains("kids") && $1.gradeLongName().contains("kids"))
    && !($0.gradeLongName().contains("juniors") && $1.gradeLongName().contains("juniors"))
})
```

Should do the trick. The closure says two elements are in the right order if the first one has kids in it, the second one has juniors in it or they are alphabetically in the right order. The last two subexpressions make the closure return false when two elements both have kids or both have juniors which is a requirement for the API

You can also use trailing closure syntax here:

```
let sortedArray = user.sorted{ ($0.gradeLongName().contains("kids") 
     || $1.gradeLongName()contains("juniors")  
     || $0.gradeLongName() < $1.gradeLongName())
    && !($0.gradeLongName().contains("kids") && $1.gradeLongName().contains("kids")
    && !(($0.gradeLongName().contains("juniors") && $1.gradeLongName().contains("juniors")) }
```

Also you can do an in place sort on a mutable array with `sort(by:)`

API docs are here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2296815-sorted

Comment: Thank you so much! This is perfect. Fixed my version of the array sort as follows. Very short and clean ;-)
`let sortedArray = self.userArray.sorted(by: { $0.SchoolGrade!.gradeLongName().contains("Kids") || $1.SchoolGrade!.gradeLongName().contains("Juniors") || $0.SchoolGrade!.gradeLongName().components(separatedBy: ",").last! < $1.SchoolGrade!.gradeLongName().components(separatedBy: ",").last!
                })`

Comment: Wait, the comma check was not necessary at all because the array contained two separate elements, not one string with a comma. The following was enough :D `let sortedArray = self.userArray.sorted(by: { $0.SchoolGrade!.gradeLongName().contains("Kids") || $1.SchoolGrade!.gradeLongName().contains("Juniors")`

Answer (score 0):

You should create three separate arrays, use `filter` to get the appropriate results, then sort them individually. After that, you should join the three arrays by a simple additional operation.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to sort is not common sort routine. So firstly, check your data structure for better sort solution.

But if you insist use your string list to sort, then you can try the following code (**very ugly**) which can be run on the playground:

```
import UIKit

var array = [String]()
array.append("User1, 1st grade")
array.append("User2, 1st grade")
array.append("User3, kids")
array.append("User4, 6th grade")
array.append("User5, 5th grade")
array.append("User6, 2nd grade")
array.append("User7, kids")
array.append("User8, Juniors")

let kidsArray = array.filter { $0.lowercased().contains("kids") }.sorted()
let gradeArray = array.filter { $0.lowercased().contains("grade") }.sorted { $0.components(separatedBy: ",").last! < $1.components(separatedBy: ",").last! }
let juniorArray = array.filter { $0.lowercased().contains("juniors") }.sorted()

var finalArray = [String]()
finalArray.append(contentsOf: kidsArray)
finalArray.append(contentsOf: gradeArray)
finalArray.append(contentsOf: juniorArray)

print(finalArray)
```

Print:

["User3, kids", "User7, kids", "User1, 1st grade", "User2, 1st grade", "User6, 2nd grade", "User5, 5th grade", "User4, 6th grade", "User8, Juniors"]

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, but my array did not contain one long string. My model was fine, I just needed to compare two elements and position them.